# How to replace "S" in a formula to be able to have a variable instead of this letter S?

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I think the question is simple, the answer maybe not.

```
Sheet1.Cells().Value = "=SUM(E" & i & ":S" & i & ")/" & n
```

In short, I would like to replace the letter S with a variable (from E to AB, I don't stop to Z!) to be able to put this simple formula in a serie of cells.
When writing this question, I was thinking of using an array. I think I will have a look in this direction. But, if you have a more simple answer, do not hesitate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the obvious answer is:

```
Dim ColEnd As String

ColEnd = "X"    ' X is anything between E and AB
Sheet1.Cells().Value = "=SUM(E" & i & ":" & ColEnd & i & ")/" & n
```

Am I missing something?

If `ColEnd` needs to be a number, this will perform the conversion:

```
Public Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim ColCode As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  '   2004?  Originally written for two character codes for Excel 2003.
  '          Date not recorded.
  '  3Feb12  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  '  5Jul20  I coded the routine below before I properly understood the Range
  '          property Address. Once I understood it, I assumed the following
  '          would be faster:
  '             Dim Addr As String
  '             Addr = Cells(1, ColNum).Address
  '             ColNumToCode = Mid(Addr, 2, Len(Addr) - 3)
  '          However, when I timed the two approaches, I found:
  '            * the Address property technique was 6.0 times slower
  '              than the code below for columns 1 to 26 (A to Z)
  '            * the Address property technique was 3.8 times slower
  '              than the code below for columns 27 to 702 (AA to ZZ)
  '            * the Address property technique was 2.9 times slower
  '              than the code below for columns 703 to 16834 (AAA to XFD)

  If ColNum = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert False
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = ColCode

End Function
```

Comment: Yes, I finally did something like that with an array col = Array("E", "F",..., col being a variant instead of your ColEnd. I like the idea of the function, I suppose you meant ColNumToCode and not NewColNumToCode. The idea with FormulaR1C1 sounds good, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @JLuc01  Sorry, yes `NewColNumToCode` should have been `ColNumToCode`.  Actually, this is not as good a routine as I thought.  I have used a different routine for years to perform this conversion but I have always assumed this method would be faster. I had coded it as `NewColNumToCode`, to test it worked, before posting and did a poor job of removing the `New`.  I have since timed it and using property `Address` is way slower than coding the conversion in VBA.  I will post a faster routine if you wish.

Comment: I can see that having an array of "E" to "AB" might be faster if you have a small number of columns.  But what if you want to convert column 16384 to "XFD"?

Comment: I am alright with what I got, but if you have a faster and better routine, I will be really happy to see it, always happy to learn more.

Comment: @JLuc01  I have included my faster routine in my answer together with the timings that revealed it was the faster technique.  I have this routine within my PERSONAL.XLXB so it is available to all my workbooks.  An array is probably faster in your limited case but, for me, it would be bespoke code.  I have used this routine in hundreds of macros.  I avoid bespoke code because I value my time creating new code more than the saving of a few milliseconds of runtime.

Comment: Thanks, your function works well and that is what I call a nice piece of coding even if in my case, it could be an overkill!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FormulaR1C1` property to determine your formula by numbers, you will able to create an array. For example, instead of referring to cell `E1` in the formula, you would refer to cell `R1C5`. Also, you need to change `i` to `CStr(i)` in the formulas to be able to concatenate strings.

Comment: This idea sounds good, but I couldn't make it work. Apparently, Sheet3.Cells(i, iNR + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & i & "]C[5]:R[" & i & "]C[" & iNR - 1 & "])/" & n does not work but Sheet3.Cells(i, iNR + 5).Value = "=SUM(E" & i & ":" & col(iNR - 1) & i & ")/" & n works well. I can't see a syntax error on the first line of coding.

Comment: Although it might be clearer if you change `i` to `CStr(i)`, it is not necessary.  VBA will perform implicit conversions when this is possible.   An integer will be converted to a string or a single or a boolean if the expression requires it.  You can also write `I = I + "5"` and the "5" will be converted to an integer.  Implicit conversions are very helpful for the programmer but you must be careful.  If you define a numeric variable as a String, you will not be warned and the interpreter will convert back and forth as necessary.  It will work but it will be slow.

Comment: Note that the brackets are for RELATIVE formulas, removing them will give you ABSOLUTE formulas. For example, `Cells(3, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=sqrt(R[1]C[-1])"` equivalent to `Cells(3, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=sqrt(R4C6)"`

Comment: Also, although not changing `i` to `CStr(i)` works for some circumstances, it does NOT work some times either. And when that happens (which happened to me in the past), you will not know where your code is wrong. So listen to me mate, use `CStr()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I decided to go for Tony's method. But, I will remember the property FormulaR1C1 which I don't use often enough I think.